# How do I join a Y variable to each X variable in a dataframe?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, merge

I have a data frame of 200 X variables and 1 Y variable.
I want to separate each X variables and join each with a Y variable.
For example,

```
X1=rnorm(10, mean=5, as=2)
X2=rnorm(10, mean=5, as=2)
X2=rnorm(10, mean=5, as=2)
yvar=runif(10, 6,9)
```

And the X variables are in the dataframe `rand_data`

```
rand_data=cbind(X1,X2,X3)
```

I used this code:

```
for (i in length (p)){ #p is the number of X variables
    s=matrix (0, nrow=10, ncol=2)
    for( j in p[i])
    s= cbind(yvar, rand_data[ ,i]) #rand_data is the matrix containing #all the X variables and yvar is the y variable
    }
}
```

I am getting a data frame of 2 variables and what I want is a list of dataframes with two variables each.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be

```
nm1 <- setdiff(names(df1), "Y")
lapply(nm1, function(x) cbind(df1["Y"], df1[x]))
```

---

Another would be

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(nm1, ~
         df1 %>% 
             select(Y, .x))
```

Comment: @BridgeSmith  Your title says to join Y variable with each X variable and the code is doing that

Comment: I have gotten it, I made a mistake in the lines